# Inverse Calculation

Tags: c#

i want get **t** from encoded byte

**Encode Code**

```
byte enc(int t, int k)
{
    k %= 8;
    return (byte)(((t << k) | (t >> (8 - k))) & 0xff);
}
```

**Tried**

```
(65132 & 0xff) | ~0xff
```

**Result**

```
-148
```

**Want**

```
int dec(byte enc, int k)
    return t; // how to calculate t?
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? Why you encode an `int` number but decode you want get a `byte`? The normal way should be encode an `int` to other `int`, then decode back to original `int`, or encode a `byte` to other `byte`, then decode back to original `byte`. Did you tried type the code to Visual Studio? The `enc` function above clearly not from working code.

Comment: Did you tried the `enc` function in Visual Studio? it is an error code. We can only help you if you post here real code.

Comment: sorry edited question

Comment: If you want encode an `int`, your `enc` must change to `int enc(int t, int k)`. If you want encode a `byte`, it must change to `byte enc(byte t, int k)`. What you are doing now is encode an `int` to a `byte`, then decode this `byte` to original `int`. That is impossible, because when encode `int` to `byte`, data already being loss

Comment: however byte enc(byte t, byte k) function can decode to byte ?

Comment: Did Kote's answer solve your problem or not?

Comment: yeah kote's answer right

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write decode function, you need to know how your encode function works.
In this case it takes `k` right-most bytes and places its in tail.
E.g `1101` will be encoded to `0111`.
So if you want to decode, you need to do opposite operations.

```
public static byte dec(byte enc, int k)
{
    k %= 8;
    return (byte)((enc >> k) | (enc << (8 - k)));
}
```

But if you are encoding your `int` to `byte` you may lose some information.
E.g you can't encode big enough number like `1234567890` to `byte` and then decode it.
But you can encode your `int` to array of bytes and then decode it from array.